# Error on adding winston log to electron angular application

Tags: angular, electron, angular7, angular8

I am working on angular electron applciation. I am trying to add winston logger to my application. After configuring winston-logger.ts file when I run application using npm run electron, I am getting following errors

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/tail-file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\node_modules\winston\dist\winston'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/http.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'http' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/http.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'https' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/logform/node_modules/colors/lib/system/supports-colors.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\logform\node_modules\colors\lib\system'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/exception-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/rejection-handler.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/stream.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/console.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
ERROR in ./node_modules/winston/dist/winston/transports/file.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'zlib' in 'C:\Users\winston\dist\winston\transports'
```

How to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

require the winston module using

```
 const winston = <any>window.require('winston');
```

require alone doesnt work.

Comment: where I need to add this line?

Comment: I am using typescript so imported winston like this import * as winston from "winston";

Comment: property require  doesnot exist on type window

Comment: you have to enable nodeIntegration to the window; did you do that/